# Kotlin lambda with Interface as an argument

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin

I'm a bit baffled by the Koltin lambdas and I wanted to know how to use it given the following snippet of code:

```
interface KotlinInterface {

    fun doStuff(str: String): String
}
```

And the function that requires this Interface to be passed as a parameter:

```
fun kotlinInterfaceAsArgument(kotlinInterface: KotlinInterface): String{

   return kotlinInterface.doStuff("This was passed to Kotlin Interface method")
}

fun main(args: Array<String>){

    val newString = kotlinInterfaceAsArgument({
      str -> str + " | It's here" //error here (type mismatch)
    })
}
```

However, the same logic but in Java compiles and runs as intended.

```
public class JavaClass {

   public String javaInterfaceAsArgument(JavaInterface javaInterface){

        String passedToInterfaceMethod = "This was passed to Java Interface method";
        return javaInterface.doStuff(passedToInterfaceMethod);
    }

   public interface JavaInterface {

        public String doStuff(String str);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JavaClass javaClass = new JavaClass();
        String newValue = javaClass.javaInterfaceAsArgument(str -> str + " | It's here!");

        System.out.println(newValue);
    }
}
```

How can I utilize lambda in Kotlin in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio converting Java to Kotlin error Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247827/android-studio-converting-java-to-kotlin-error-cannot-infer-a-type-for-this-para)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) (as of 1.1) only works with Java interfaces, not Kotlin ones.

> Also note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported.

You can see some ways to fix your code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44247978/4465208).

**Edit:** I've realized this is an exact duplicate of the other question, as even the error is the same.

Comment: So, `fun main(args: Array<String>) {
 println(JavaClass().javaInterfaceAsArgument { it -> it+" | It's here " })
}` is the correct answer?

Comment: Well, having the interface defined in Java is one of the options.

Comment: Cool thanks. The above one worked for me without the need of creating an interface and function in kotlin.

Comment: @zsmb13 Ok, got it. I guess, as for now if somebody wants to go pure Kotlin, he should use something like this.  `val value = kotlinInterfaceAsArgument(object: KotlinInterface {
      override fun doStuff(str: String): String {
         return str + "| "
      }
   })`

Comment: @MaximMaliarov no, when you go pure kotlin dont create interfaces with a single method at all! rather use function types e. g. `doStuff: (String) -> String`

Answer (score 2):

The proper way in pure Kotlin is to use higher-order functions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

With higher-order function you can pass function as argument in it.

If we talk about your example:

```
fun kotlinFunctionAsArgument(kotlinFunction: (String) -> String): String {
    return kotlinFunction("This was passed to Kotlin Function method")
}

fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val newString = kotlinFunctionAsArgument({
        str -> str + " | It's here" //there are no errors
    })
}
```